# imenu in ess-mode: recognize assignment with "="

Tags: ess, imenu

Is there a way to configure the imenu integration in ESS-mode so that it recognizes assignment by the equal sign "=", not only by arrow "<-"?

I'm switching between R and python so I've switched to "=" to decrease the cognitive load, but this way I loose the imenu functionality...

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ESS now recognizes `=` as an assignment operator for imenu's purposes. You can get this using MELPA or wait for the next official release.